# Delete old files in large folder

Tags: ssh, find

I have a folder which contains many files. I want to delete files older than 30 days, so I use the command:

```
find cache/ -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

But my SSH session disconnects before the command completes.

How can I limit the number of files that are deleted at one time? For example:

```
find cache/ -mtime +30 -LIMIT 10000 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "timeout"?

Comment: wait a longtime and putty show disconnect

Answer (score 5):

Run it in a `screen` session.  That way when putty disconnects the job is still running on the server.  Just reconnect and use `screen -r` to re-attach the screen session to see the progress.

Comment: how to run in screen session?

Comment: just run the `screen` command and it will create a new screen session for you.  It's probably best to skim through the man page for screen, but I guarantee you it will quickly become one of your most used tools.  Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

You could also run the command with `nohup`, like this:

```
nohup find cache/ -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \; &
```

Then `cat nohup.out` to keep an eye on the ouput.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like:

```
find cache/ -mtime +30 | head -n 10000 | xargs rm
```

This would work if the filenames were fairly "vanilla" (no spaces, special characters, etc) and short.

But if you'd rather just wait for your original command to complete, you can just tell PuTTY to send SSH keepalive messages every so often; see [the PuTTY docs](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.55/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#S4.13.4) for the details. I usually use a value between 45–60 seconds, myself.

Answer (score 2):

```
find cache/ -mtime +30 -print0 | xargs -0 rm -v
```

Then it'll output every file that is deleted, that should prevent your session from timing out .

Or, put this in cron, as it's something that sounds like it should be automated.